# What does resetting the PMU do?

Tags: power-management

I am considering resetting the PMU on my Mac, but I'm am unsure what it exactly does. I know it resets date/time, but what other settings does it wipe?

Comment: What problems are you experiencing? Can you provide some detail on why you feel you need to reset the PMU/SMC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379) has a [link](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1895) that explains what happens when the PMU is reset. Three things are reset:

1. Speaker volume
2. Screen resolution
3. Startup disk selection

> After resetting NVRAM or PRAM you may need to reconfigure your settings for speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information.

and this list (may not apply to all Macs):

> ```
> Status of AppleTalk
> Serial Port Configuration and Port definition
> Alarm clock setting
> Application font
> Serial printer location
> Autokey rate
> Autokey delay
> Speaker volume
> Attention (beep) sound
> Double-click time
> Caret blink time (insertion point rate)
> Mouse scaling (mouse speed)
> Startup disk
> Menu blink count
> Monitor depth
> 32-bit addressing
> Virtual memory
> RAM disk
> Disk cache
> ```

Another [support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1242) provides additional information:

> Some information stored in PRAM includes:
>
> - Display and video settings such as refresh rate, screen resolution, number of colors
> - Startup volume choice
> - Speaker volume
> - Recent kernel panic information, if any
> - DVD region setting
>
>   Note: Mac OS X stores your preselected DVD region choice in PRAM for easy access. Resetting PRAM does not allow you to change the DVD
>   region.